# How to display this HTML string in echo php function

Tags: php, echo

I'm a newbie in php... I have a form who pass a username variable to a php scrit, this is the code..
`<form action="bottone.php" method="get"> Inserisci il tuo nome utente: <input name="username" type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="GENERA CODICE" /> </form>`

I would like to display this HTML code in the botton.php script:

```
<a href=www.mysite.com/$username <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="La mia pagina su Mysite"/></a>
```

where $username is the variable passed from the form... how can I do that with an echo function??
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

like this:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/'.$username.'"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="La mia pagina su Mysite"/></a>';
?>
```

Or, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/<?=$username?>"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="La mia pagina su Mysite"/></a>
```

You may want to make sure $username is safe though... at least use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), or something similar.

****EDIT****
I had assumed you already knew how to get $username from the form you mentioned, but in case you didn't, you would just do:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

Or you could use this as an opportunity to use those functions I mentioned above (unless you will be needing $username for some other purpose before echoing it out.

Example:

```
$username = urlencode($_GET['username']);
```

Or you could do this straight in the echo like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/<?=urlencode($_GET['username'])?>"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="La mia pagina su Mysite"/></a>
```

Comment: Option #2 is better. Simply add `htmlspecialchars()`. :)

Comment: I prefer option #2 myself. Would htmlspcialchars() be better than urlencode() in this case?

Comment: You insert the `$username` into the `href` attribute, so it's a URL. `(raw)urlencode` is the way to go here! :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was a rawurldecode. Interesting, thanks! http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/" . htmlspecialchars($username) . "\"><img src=\"http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"La mia pagina su Mysite\"/></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose echo in double quotes and the html attributes in single quotes

Use the below code if u get the username from form.

> $username= htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['username']);

or Use the below code if u assign the variable.

> $username= htmlspecialchars(your text goes here...);

```
echo "<a href= 'http://www.mysite.com/$username'><img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg' width='50' height='50' alt='La mia pagina su Mysite'></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo sprintf('<a href="http://www.mysite.com/%s"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="La mia pagina su Mysite"/></a>', htmlspecialchars($username, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.