# How to insert HTML Tags in plain text

Tags: html, text, insert, tags

I have plan to insert HTML tags in plain text. But i don't have idea for that. I have a plan text "Core Features" and i'd like to insert with HTML tags, so that would be "`<span class="text-danger">Core</span> Features`". Thanks for your great idea...

Comment: Insert it into what?

Comment: insert into plain Text... as I said before that I have plain text "Core Features"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean html entities encoding. So your example will be:

```
&#x3C;span class=&#x22;text-danger&#x22;&#x3E;Core&#x3C;/span&#x3E; Features
```

You can play with encoding here: https://mothereff.in/html-entities

Comment: I am sorry, that's not what I mean... I mean HTML tags such as span, b, div, etc... I have PHP string text and I want to insert in that string with the HTML tags

Comment: Then this might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674727/how-to-display-this-html-string-in-echo-php-function

Comment: thanks for your response, but it's still not help... because that's not what I mean.... I'll give you example.  I have string `$title = "Core Features"` and when I print this string  `echo $title`, then I want to have the result including the HTML Tags. So the result should be `<span class="text-danger">Core</span> Features`